Firebase functions imports in firebase functions 6.0.1
In firebase-functions 3.13.2 I was able to import using typescript:
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { UserRecord } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth';

These import statements do not work with firebase-functions 6.0.1
I get these errors:

error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' or its
corresponding type declarations.
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
error TS2307: Cannot find module
'firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth' or its corresponding type
declarations.
import { UserRecord } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth';

There are examples using require e.g. const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");
Is it possible to use import with firebase-functions 6.0.1?
How do I import the type definition of UserRecord from firebase-functions 6.0.1?

Firstly, import * as functions from 'firebase-functions' should compile just fine.  It does for me.  If it doesn't for you, maybe there is something wrong with your setup.  But you probably don't want to use the wildcard import given the way that v1 and v2 functions differ in what they require to import.
Secondly, you can import UserRecord like this:
import { UserRecord } from "firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity"

For example, if you're trying to write an onCreate auth function, this compiles for me:
import { auth } from "firebase-functions/v1"
import { UserRecord } from "firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity"

export const functionName = auth.user().onCreate((user: UserRecord) => {
    // ...
})


Thanks for the reply. Yes, it might be my setup. Are you using commonjs or ems? Could you post your tsconfig.json?

This should work with whatever the Firebase CLI provides when you create a new project and choose TypeScript for Cloud Functions.

the problem I had seemed to be because I did not have firebase or firebase-functions in the package.json of the parent directory above the functions directory. The target in the tsconfig.json generated by firebase init functions also created weird compilation problems until I switched to esnext.

There does not seem to be a UserRecord in 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth'. Referencing it by auth.UserRecord works fine though. Thanks for your help.

But that's not the import I show in the answer.  It's firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity.
